# Is a right inverse of a element in a unital banach algebra also a left inverse?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-algebras

I am reading the proof of the following theorem from a set of notes:
[image]

I am trying to figure out why the highlighted expression cannot have an inverse. Is it because if it does have an inverse, that would imply $\lambda -x$ has a right inverse which is also its left inverse so it would be invertible which is impossible since $\lambda$ is in the spectrum of $x$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the two elements in your product commute. ($\lambda$ is a scalar, so it belongs to the center of the algebra) So if the product is invertible then $\lambda-x$ has both a right and left inverse. And it is a basic result that if an element in any unital ring has both a left and right inverse then the element is invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering, if elements did not commute, then this does not have to be true correct?

Comment: @Bill Not necessary. To answer the question in the title, an element can have only a one sided inverse. For example, suppose $A$ is the Banach algebra of bounded linear operators on the space $\ell^2$. The operator $T(x_1, x_2,...)=(0, x_1, x_2,...)$ only has the left inverse $S(x_1, x_2,...)=(x_2, x_3,...)$, but not a right inverse. (clearly $T$ is not surjective) So similarly, the operator $S$ only has a right inverse.

Comment: ok got it.  thanks :)